# how to read zvpl file

Tags: .net

How to read a zvpl file in window and also convert the .zvpl file into .txt file?

Comment: As in a Visual Paradigm for UML file? Why would you want to do this? It's not really a programming question.

Comment: Programmatically? Is a .zvpl file a Visual Paradigm for UML file?

Answer (score 0):

According to the information on [FILExt](http://filext.com/file-extension/ZVPL) .zvpl files start with the following byte sequence:

```
80 7F 50 4B 03 04
```

Starting from the third byte this looks exactly like a zip file, so my bet would be that you can open the file with WinZip (or any other zip tool) as soon as you strip the first two bytes. If you did this you can inspect the file for its further structure.